# Is there a way to get the users home path as a string in windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm dynamically reading in XML files from the hard disk. 
On OSX i can use getenv("HOME") function to get the home directory.
However this doesn't work on Windows for me. when using the getenv() function on Windows instead of the username i just get a dot.
Is there a function that gives me the root directory as a string that works on Windows and OSX ?

```cpp
string  HOME = getenv("HOME") ? getenv("HOME") : ".";
string homePath;
string s1 = HOME;
string s2 = "/Documents/Resolume Arena 6/Preferences/AdvancedOutput.xml";
homePath = s1 + s2;

    cout << "preferences path: " << homePath << endl;
```

this gives me:

"preferences path: ./Documents/Resolume Arena 6/Preferences/AdvancedOutput.xml"

Comment: try opening a console and write `set` to see all the available environment variables. make sure the one you are looking for is there. On WIndows 10, I see there is `USERPROFILE` that could do the trick, but it's probably version-specific for Win 10.
[Environment variables for windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables)
Wrap that in a function call with architecture-specific compiler directives are you're good to go.
`#ifdef _WIN32 #elif _APPLE_ #endif`

Comment: Preferences in Windows are stored either in the per-user registry (via the predefined Key handle `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`) in a subkey of "Software", or in a subdirectory of either the local or roaming application data directory, determined via [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath). It goes against platform convention to store preferences directly in the user's profile directory (i.e. `"%USERPROFILE%"`) or home directory (i.e. `"%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"`, by default the same as the profile directory).

Comment: Some applications may store configuration data in the user's "Documents" folder, as your example code suggests. This is strange and against most conventions, but for the sake of completeness, use [`FOLDERID_Documents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/knownfolderid#FOLDERID_Documents) to get this folder location. Do not use `"%USERPROFILE%\\Documents"`. That's not simply against convention; it's simply wrong. The user can easily relocate this special folder to an arbitrary location.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you [should store application preferences in a folder inside `%AppData%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/win_cert/certification-requirements-for-windows-desktop-apps#10-apps-must-install-to-the-correct-folders-by-default).

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#endif

...

string homePath;
#ifdef _WIN32
CHAR buf[MAX_PATH+100];
if (!SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(0, buf, CSIDL_APPDATA, TRUE))
{
  // Handle error
}
PathAppendA(buf, "MyCompany\\MyApplication);
homePath = buf
#else
homePath = ...; // OSX code
#endif
cout << "preferences path: " << homePath << endl;
```

On Windows you should not really use `CHAR`, `string` and the `A` suffix functions, ideally you should be using Unicode (UTF-16LE) which means `WCHAR`, `wstring` and the `W` functions.

Comment: @eryksun Yes, Unicode is preferred, I noted this in my answer but it can be problematic in large cross-platform projects. Using the known folder API is unnecessary for the classic special folders IMHO. SHGetSpecialFolderPath just calls SHGetFolderPath and it was the primary function back in the day, Microsoft is not going to break this.